# How to verify subtraction of mocked classes?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm stuck on a unit test I'm working on for the following:

```
if(dsIn.getItemNumber(1,"CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_AMT") != null)
{
    dsIn.setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", Double.valueOf(newValueIn)-dsIn.getItemNumber(1,"CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT"));
}
else
{
    dsIn.setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", Double.valueOf(newValueIn));
}
```

I was able to mock the second case when `getItemNumber() == null` but I am struggling with finding the proper way to verify that the first case is executing and returning the appropriate number after the subtraction. I have tried writing the following test case for it :

```
@Test
public void testUncheckedApproved() throws TRDIException, IOException{


    Mockito.when(dsIn.getItemNumber(1,"CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT")).thenReturn(4.0);
    evaluate();

    Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", Double.valueOf(newValueIn)) - Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT", 
    Double.valueOf(newValueIn));
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, and I've also tried to verify each method separately, but that is not the way to do it. The 'verify' method is incorrect. I just need to figure out this line.

Comment: What does `evaluate()` do?

Comment: I've got to understand first the logic behind the tested code, first. What is the first `if` for? The field `CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_AMT` is not used after.

Comment: @LittleSanti it invokes the method that is being mocked. The logic is essentially: getItemNumber() grabs a number from the column 'CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_AMT'. If it is not null, set the number in the datastore (dsIn) to the amount from colulmn '"CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT"' (which will be 1, since newValueIn = 1) minus the amount from column 'CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_AMT'. Else, set the datastore value to "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", which is newValueIn.

Comment: May I suggest you review your tested code's logic? The column being substracted is `CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT`, not `CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_AMT` as you say.

Comment: Sorry, this was a quick copy paste with some rough edits. I updated the code being tested to match the test. The verify line in the test is not working. I'm  not sure how to properly verify the subtraction

Answer (score 0):

I think the second `verify` is wrong. You posted:

```
Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", Double.valueOf(newValueIn)) - Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT", 
Double.valueOf(newValueIn));
```

But it should be:

```
double d1=Mockito.verify(dsIn).getItemNumber(1,"CC_FY_APPR_OBLIG_YTD_AMT");
double d2=Double.valueOf(newValueIn)-d1;
Mockito.verify(dsIn).setItemNumber(1, "CC_FY_UNOBLIG_AMT", d2);
```

(I omitted to check for the number of times these methods are invoked, since they should be invoked just once).